# Google maps API: accepting search address of the same radius using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

What I want to achieve is to accept a client-side address of the same radius within and if the address is not of the same radius it should validate("address not accepted") or it should not work.

1. when a client or user enters an address of the same address within the radius it should validate("accepted")
2. when a client or user enters an address of not the same address within the radius it should validate("not accepted")

below is the code I tried to do:-

```
 <html>
<title></title>
<head></head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("maps", "3",{other_params:"key="});
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var map = null;
  var radius_circle;
  var markers_on_map = [];
  var geocoder;
  var infowindow;

  //all_locations is just a sample, you will probably load those from database
   var all_locations = [
  {type: "Restaurant", name: "Restaurant 1", lat: 40.723080, lng: -73.984340},
  {type: "School", name: "School 1", lat: 40.724705, lng: -73.986611},
  {type: "School", name: "School 2", lat: 40.724165, lng: -73.983883},
  {type: "Restaurant", name: "Restaurant 2", lat: 40.721819, lng: -73.991358},
  {type: "School", name: "School 3", lat: 40.732056, lng: -73.998683}
  ];

   //initialize map on document ready
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.723080, -73.984340); //you can use any location as center 
   on map startup
   var myOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(){
       if(infowindow){
         infowindow.setMap(null);
         infowindow = null;
       }
     });
    });

  function showCloseLocations() {
  var i;
  var radius_km = $('#radius_km').val();
  var address = $('#address').val();

  //remove all radii and markers from map before displaying new ones
   if (radius_circle) {
    radius_circle.setMap(null);
    radius_circle = null;
   }
  for (i = 0; i < markers_on_map.length; i++) {
    if (markers_on_map[i]) {
        markers_on_map[i].setMap(null);
        markers_on_map[i] = null;
    }
}

if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                var address_lat_lng = results[0].geometry.location;
                radius_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: address_lat_lng,
                    radius: radius_km * 1000,
                    clickable: false,
                    map: map
                });
                if (radius_circle) map.fitBounds(radius_circle.getBounds());
                for (var j = 0; j < all_locations.length; j++) {
                    (function (location) {
                        var marker_lat_lng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
                        var distance_from_location = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(address_lat_lng, marker_lat_lng); //distance in meters between your location and the marker
                        if (distance_from_location <= radius_km * 1000) {
                            var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: marker_lat_lng,
                                map: map,
                                title: location.name
                            });                                     google.maps.event.addListener(new_marker, 'click', function () {
                                if(infowindow){
         infowindow.setMap(null);
         infowindow = null;
       }
                                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        { content: '<div style="color:red">'+location.name +'</div>' + " is " + distance_from_location + " meters from my location",
          size: new google.maps.Size(150,50),
          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
        , position: marker_lat_lng, map: map});
                            });
                            markers_on_map.push(new_marker);
                        }
                    })(all_locations[j]);
                }
            } else {
                alert("No results found while geocoding!");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful: " + status);
        }
    });
}
  }
</script>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" >
<input id="address" value="Second Steet, New York" placeholder="Input Address"/>
 <select id="radius_km">
 <option value=1>1km</option>
 <option value=2>2km</option>
 <option value=5>5km</option>
 <option value=30>30km</option>
 </select>
 <button onClick="showCloseLocations()">Show Locations In Radius</button>
 <div id="map_canvas"  style="width:500px; height:300px;">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that the posted code doesn't do?

Comment: This code does not validate the location within the radius

Comment: So you mean any address the user types that is outside "Second Steet, New York" should not be accepted as valid input? I'm not clear either on what the problem is.

Comment: @evan Yes, correct. That's what I want.

Comment: You for reference you can check the app called laundryapp, how they used the address. I think its the perfect example of what I need currently. @evan

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your `showCloseLocations` function with the following:

```
  function showCloseLocations() {
    var i;
    var radius_km = $('#radius_km').val();
    var address = $('#address').val();

    for (i = 0; i < markers_on_map.length; i++) {
      if (markers_on_map[i]) {
        markers_on_map[i].setMap(null);
        markers_on_map[i] = null;
      }
    }

    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

            var address_lat_lng = results[0].geometry.location;

            if (radius_circle) {
              radius_circle.setRadius(radius_km * 100);
            }
            else {
              radius_circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: address_lat_lng,
                radius: radius_km * 1000,
                clickable: false,
                map: map
              });
            }

            if (!radius_circle.getBounds().contains(address_lat_lng)) {
              alert("This address is outside radius.");
              return;
            }

            if (radius_circle) map.fitBounds(radius_circle.getBounds());

            for (var j = 0; j < all_locations.length; j++) {
              (function(location) {
                var marker_lat_lng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.lat, location.lng);
                var distance_from_location = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(address_lat_lng, marker_lat_lng); //distance in meters between your location and the marker
                if (distance_from_location <= radius_km * 1000) {
                  var new_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: marker_lat_lng,
                    map: map,
                    title: location.name
                  });
                  google.maps.event.addListener(new_marker, 'click', function() {
                    if (infowindow) {
                      infowindow.setMap(null);
                      infowindow = null;
                    }
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content: '<div style="color:red">' + location.name + '</div>' + " is " + distance_from_location + " meters from my location",
                      size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50),
                      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30),
                      position: marker_lat_lng,
                      map: map
                    });
                  });
                  markers_on_map.push(new_marker);
                }
              })(all_locations[j]);
            }
          }
          else {
            alert("No results found while geocoding!");
          }
        }
        else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

The above code uses [`LatLngBounds.contains`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngBounds.contains) to validate whether the input address's `LatLng` is within the circle's bounds. So any address that is outside the given radius for "Second Steet, New York" will be deemed invalid.

Hope this is the behavior you wanted. Let me know if not so that I can modify my answer accordingly.